# WebView OnScaleChanged Min & Max

Tags: android, android-webview, scale, pinchzoom

I have implemented a webview in my project, where I need to show a pdf. I enabled pinch to zoom without any problem, i also have two button to control zoom in & zoom out. I need to disable their if "scaling" will reach maximum and minimum.

At this moment i'm using `canZoomIn` & `canZoomOut` method in `OnScaleChanged` listener and it works but if you read in androidDevelopers official their doesn't reccomend it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#canZoomIn()

> This method is prone to inaccuracy due to race conditions between the
> web rendering and UI threads; prefer WebViewClient#onScaleChanged.

My question is: How can i know when user reach min and max without `canZoomIn` & `canZoomOut` ?

```
override fun onScaleChanged(view: WebView?, oldScale: Float, newScale: Float) {
    super.onScaleChanged(view, oldScale, newScale)
    bottomBarView.setEnabledItem(view!!.canZoomIn(),ENBottomBarItem.zoomIn)
    bottomBarView.setEnabledItem(view.canZoomOut(),ENBottomBarItem.zoomOut)
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some code snippets so that we can try it on our end?

Comment: @MayurGajra Posted my code...